# Quantum algorithm for QR and SVD matrix decomposition?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I would like to know if exist a quantum algorithm tailored to compute the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) and [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of a matrix? Pointers to relevant papers will be very appreciated.

Comment: Does this help: [Quantum circuits synthesis using Householdertransformations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.07710.pdf)...?

Comment: I don't think so, I am afraid because their algorithm uses classical QR as the first step, but they aren't proposing a quantum algorithm to perform QR decomposition.

Comment: Hmm, ok right. How do you think to store the input $A$ and output $Q$ and $R$?
BTW: Householder trafo is mentioned on the [Grover' search Wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm#The_first_iteration)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find a few research papers with the potential application of quantum algorithms for Singular Value Decomposition and QR decomposition.

**Singular Value Decomposition:**
Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) is one of the most useful techniques for analyzing data in linear algebra. SVD decomposes a rectangular real or complex matrix into two orthogonal matrices and one diagonal matrix. The following research paper proposes a Quantum-SVD algorithm that interpolates the non-uniform angles in the Fourier domain. This Quantum-SVD algorithm is a fundamentally novel approach for the computation of the Quantum Fourier Transformation (QFT) of non-uniform states.

We can also consider Schmidt decomposition approach for Singular Value Decomposition as per the researches in Quantum Information Theory. It is considered as a Schmidt decomposition has a lot of applications for bipartite state purification.

[Quantum SVD based Approximation Algorithm](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S0218126610006797)

**QR Factorisation**

Following research paper proposes a rotation graph to devise elimination orderings in order to achieve QR factorisations. Properties of this graph characterise and identify sufficient sets of rotation planes. The unitary or real orthogonal matrix Q is usually computed in one of three ways: Givens rotations, Householder reflections, or Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. A Givens-based decomposition is also an essential tool in quantum computing. It is important to determine whether a given set of rotation planes
can be used to reduce a matrix to upper triangular form using a minimal number of
rotations. One interesting rotation graph is the star graph. A second interesting rotation graph is the chain.

[QR Factorisation using Rotation Graphs and Eliminated Orderings](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/oleary/tr/tr4592.pdf)

Comment: The second paper is not a quantum algorithm.